# Array Partition using Pthread in linux C

Tags: c, linux, parallel-processing, pthreads, mutex

I want to parallel merge sort's partition part, but I don't know how to continue. Please give me some ideas based on my situation, thank you!

Serial part:

```
void Partition(int arr[], int low, int high)
{
    int mid;    
    if(low < high)
    {
        mid = (low + high)/2;
        Partition(arr, low, mid); //first half of data
        Partition(arr, mid+1, high);//second half of data
        MergeSort(arr, low, mid, high);
    }
}
```

What I have for parallel version:

```
void *PartitionTask(void* rank)
{
    long my_rank = (long)rank;
    if(my_rank == 0)
    {
        int mid;    
        if(low < high)
        {
            mid = (low + high)/2;
            Partition(arr, low, mid); //first half of data
            Partition(arr, mid+1, high);//second half of data
            MergeSort(arr, low, mid, high);
        }
    }
    else
    {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most simple and direct solution would probably be to spawn a new thread for the one partition and entering the other in the calling thread.

```
pthread_create(&low_pid, NULL, Partition, (void *)ptr_argument)
```

With the `ptr_argument` as a pointer to a shared memory struct containing the pointer to arr and low/high values.

When the calling thread returns, call `pthread_join` with `low_pid` to synchronize before mergeing.

Comment: @alk Yes, of course! Typed it wrong while looking up the man page as well, habits from Erlang creeping my C. Thank you for pointing that out (:

Comment: @Linxxon thank you! One thing I'm not sure. In serial version, it is recursively calling Partition. In pthread version, how can I do the same thing? Please give me some suggestion.

Comment: @Alison That's how I meant for you to implement. Create a new thread to handle one of the recursions and let the calling one do the other and then synchronize before calling `MergeSort`. I think would be easier to modify the serial part in your question to do this instead of continuing with what you have for the parallel version.